# "Create Team" button appearing in left sidebar, even without subscription

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, sidebar

Today I went onto Stack Overflow. A new widget had appeared in the left navigation sidebar:

[image: teams widget]

When I clicked the "Create Team" button, it invited me to begin a subscription for Stack Overflow for Teams.

Is there a reason this widget appears for me, as I do not use Teams? Possibly another way of advertising Teams?

---

Also, as @DavyM pointed out, it also appears when the sidebar is hidden:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm seeing this design:

[image]

I find this distracting and [I removed it](https://twitter.com/Kobi/status/1024177750775607296). Besides using uBlock to remove ads, I don't recall I had to remove an element from Stack Overflow.
Specifically, the button and orange circle are too bright, and the colors are over-saturated. The orange used here is the brightest thing in the entire page (again, excluding ads).

---

This is the Stylus ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) / [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en)) rule I used in the tweet:

```css
ol.nav-links li:last-child > ol.nav-links {
    display: none;
}
```

URLs matching regexp: `^https://stackoverflow.com/.*`
Title: `SO - Hide Obnoxious Create Team Button`

Comment: This answer was also sufficient for creating a Stylish override (also: I too get this style of button).

Comment: @Draco18s (off topic) You might want to [avoid Stylish](https://robertheaton.com/2018/07/02/stylish-browser-extension-steals-your-internet-history/)

Comment: @Piccolo Don't recall being aware of this, but I am on an old (non-invasive) version. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 13):

It appears there for exactly the reason of advertising Teams and making it easier to access a page where you could create one. It appearing there as a button is *because you don't use Teams* - that's very much intentional. If you were already a part of a team, you'd see a list of any teams you belong to, with a Create Team link at the bottom in case you were interested in creating another (instead of the button you see with no teams).

Comment: We have teams, we don't use it too much yet.  However, there truly will/may be people who will never want to use teams.  i think this is a mean way to advertise it.

Comment: Jokes on you, I have the entire left nav turned off, and it's not in the little hamburger menu, thankfully.

Comment: @SeinopSys Don't give them any ideas.

Answer (score 5):

To hide it, block `##.fd-column.grid.p12.mt6`. Don't know what other repercussions this has, but I don't want to see it on every page.

Comment: Are the `##` a typo in that selector, or is that some adblocker syntax I'm unaware of?

Comment: It's a filter for uBlock.

Comment: Yeah pretty sure that'll come back to bite you in the ass hiding a selector that generic which has no specificity to teams.

Comment: @Ryan well when something actually interesting comes up in the sidebar, I might re-enable it and remove the filter.

Comment: @CodeCaster but how would you know if it's hidden?

Comment: @Ryan I have a feeling that it won't be that important if something new pops up there, and if it does, I'll find out one way or another, for example by it being announced in the sidebar.

Comment: I only ever open that sidebar to hit the "Stack Overflow" button to get to the list of newest questions, so if something extra gets added there, I really wouldn't care. There's nothing else I need. Blocking it works great

Comment: Probably it should be part of the reduced ads privilege.

Answer (score 0):

And now there's a tooltip balloon pointing to the button, overlapping the page content and the X button which closes the balloon can only be clicked with a mouse (not a link, so hint-based browsers won't catch it).
Next level of annoying. Why do I need a mouse to keep using the page? Pls...

Update: Looks like it's gone. Used to not respect being acknowledged and dismissed with the X button, but it doesn't appear anymore for me, at least on this browser.

Comment: Is that this bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376612/cant-close-teams-bubble-on-ie11 ?

Comment: @rene Nope; I could click on the X, just not with the keyboard. It's not a hintable element (e.g. link) and tabbing would be infeasiblbe. Updated my answer.