# Can't close Teams bubble on IE11

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am using Internet Explorer 11 (which is [officially supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)). I am getting a bubble asking me to create a team for my workplace. The x is not clickable on this bubble. (When I click the x, nothing happens.)

The bubble appears on every page I've tried except main. I don't recall seeing this behavior an hour or two ago.

(I don't know how to use graphics programs, but hopefully the bubble is sufficiently clear in this screenshot.)

[image]

Comment: _"Support may be dropped in the future, without notice, if new functionality is implemented that cannot be made to work in Internet Explorer 11"_. I think is better if you don't tell them that some of the new stuff is broken in IE. ;)

Comment: @yivi I am already not telling them that a lot of stuff is broken. This one crosses the line from being ugly to getting my way.

Comment: Same issue here; using Safari Version 12.0.1 (13606.2.104.1.2)

Comment: In case you are curious, here's the actual behavior: https://i.imgur.com/p2Og4e9.gifv

Comment: Reproduced in IE11 and Edge 42.17134.1.0

Comment: Sheesh this bug is annoying... It's like a fly in your face; I now know why it's called a "fly out".

Comment: Working on a fix now! Looks like a problem with the `pointer-events` CSS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you very much for your report. We deployed the fix, so clicking anywhere on the blue tooltip should dismiss it. We removed the CSS rule: `pointer-events: none`, which was not working on some browsers such as IE11 and Edge.